# What would be the things to consider translating a game?

Tags: text

I suppose this is not rather common subject to bring on at this site, as it seems that most of them are related to programming; however, I wanted to ask you what would be the things to consider when translating the story(text) of a game, say, into English.

Could you give me guideline which I can work with - guideline that consists of things to consider and priorities of each thing? **For example**:

#### High Priority:

1. Consistency of how characters say throughout the game.
2. Typos
3. The most important ones.

#### Mid Priority:

1. These should be fulfilled in order to be a "pleasantly playable" game.

#### Low Priority:

1. Things that can be ignored if the time does not allow.

EDIT: For someone who may be interested in this question in the future, here is the list you can refer to.

**Grammar**: Pronouns, Prepositions, Wrong conjunction, Articles, Typos, Wrong tense, Inconsistent tense in a sentence, Too academic vocabulary

**Style**: Inconsistent accent and way characters say, Inconsistent style of text throughout the whole story, Awkward phrases, Wrongly spelled character name, Inconsistent spelling of the name of a character, Style not matching with a character(A commoner talking like a knight)

Comment: You might want to ask this at [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net)

Comment: Otoh, this is a bit of brainstorming style Q, where the person has very few clues in advance, while the subject itself indeed is important to a widespread public. This is not only about opinions, but also about coding; there are many pitfalls in creating multi-lingual applications, IF one for example decides to support multiple languages with a single codebase (which may be wiser than extracting multiple ones). Admittedly it may be broad, and/or opinion-based, but personally i'd be happy to read any thoughs nevertheless. I've avoided many problems by using descriptive images instead of words.